# Deciphering time stamps from chrome trace logs

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm using the C# binding for selenium webdriver, and there is an API for setting up and retrieving chrome performance logs while running tests.

I am looking at network response logs specifically, and contained in them are timestamps for when the request was made, and a timestamp for the response that was returned:

Example:

"requestTime": 407807.240968

"timestamp": 407809.465389

It seems pretty clear these time stamps are in seconds, so it's easy to get the elapsed time from the time the request was made to the time the response was received, but I'd like to be able to convert them to a datetime, and I can't really tell what the pattern is in order to do so.

It's obviously not seconds since epoch.  I was wondering if anyone who knew more about the underlying code could clue me in?

Comment: Do you know when you collected those logs? Were they captured today?

Comment: Yeah they were today at around 8:45 AM mountain standard time.